Finding overlapping line geometries (including subsets) in QGIS
I have a vector file with ~4000 line geometries. Some of the lines are overlapping, or more precise, it seems, that some lines are subsets of the longer geometry.
How can I find all overlapping lines in QGIS?
I cannot find such an operation in the 'topology checker' or the 'Check geometries' of QGIS. Both are just handling duplicates, but this is not what I'm searching for.

Vector Overlay - Intersection

I'm a bit surprised how tricky this appears to be. Like you say, it's straightforward enough to find duplicates, but subsets of lines not so much.
Anyway, here's a way of adding a visual indication of sub-lines to your map:
First, use the 'Points along geometry' tool in the processing toolbox with a suitably small distance values (I used 5 metres).
Then on the resulting points layer set the symbology to 'point cluster' and set the distance value to something very small, e.g. 1 millimetre. Then on your map any substrings should be highlighted with clusters (the 2's on the map below):

Not sure how infallible this is, but could be worth a go.
--EDIT--
For those lines that simply intersect, you could use the 'Line intersections' tool, using the same layer for both the 'Input layer' and 'Intersect layer'. This should create a point layer of where those intersections occur.

Thank you for trying to help! This may work for smaller datasets, but unfortunately for my case this will most possibly be not perfomant enough.
In the old ArcMap there exixt 'intersect', which will give out objects which are overlapping, and which is also very fast. I wonder why there is nothing comparably in QGIS yet.
The 'Line intersection'-tool in QGIS gives all locations, where lines are intersecting, so in fact also there where lines are touching. In a streetwork this would be a good tool to get all nodes, but unfortunately, it is not what I need for my case.

This worked for me: Use the 'Select by location'-Tool with 'overlap', and compare the layer with itself. It will select all overlapping features in the relevant layer.
I'm not completely sure how well this works (so if it reliably finds all overlaps), but it did find overlapping features and for my (now) ~ 10000 features it was relatively fast (a few seconds). You may need to separatly check for duplicated geometries, as I think this will only search for overlaps, not for duplicates.

